# Creating annual spatial index maps of Landsat collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, rgee

I am trying to create spatial annual mean index (using bands expression) maps in rstudio using rgee. I would like to use Landsat5, Landsat7 and Landsat8 L2 data.
Workflow:

1. Reading in Landsat5, Landsat7 and Landsat8 data, reading in shapefile
2. Filtering only certain months, filtering by shapefile
3. Function for cloud masking
4. Function for adding scaling factors (different functions for L57 and L8)
5. Function for calculating index using band values
6. Function for calculating annual mean values (`reducer.Mean()`)
7. Function for masking out unwanted pixels (`updateMask()`)
8. Adding the collection to bands (`toBands()`)
9. `ee_as_raster`

Everything works fine, when I use every single collection separately. The main goal is to use all the data together from Landsat578 collections. Before merging the data I select only one band which consists of my calculated index. I am able to run the code, but when I want to export the data to ee_as_raster, the user memory is exceeded (I am not able to get metadata information as well after merging the collections using ee_print, the same error, user memory exceeded). I have tried to limit the time range to fewer years, but it does not work even with one year.

Why user memory exceeds after merging the collections even when I have selected only one band and calculated annual mean values by this index (39 images of total)?

Are there some steps after merging the collections, which helps to use the data together without exceeding the user memory limit?

Sidenote, everything works fine in GEE code editor, no errors and satisfiying result, but I would like to use RStudio for better plotting possibilities.